# How to Understand Existing System

Tags: system, erp

I have to work on a existing ERP which has more then 3000 tables and 400+ ASP pages and 56+ ASPX pages .

This ERP is working perfect and i have to do some customization as per management requirement.

Now i am facing issue to start the study of the system.

Would like to know from where to start whether from DB/UI or how to map the database table

with UI OR what should be the way to study this type of big application.